# Wordpress Nginx Permalink from plain to postname

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm trying to change from plain http://sitename/?p=123 to http://sitename/postname with rewrite rule but it gives error 404 Not found. This is my nginx server block code:

```
server {

        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        root /var/www/sitename/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name sitename www.sitename;
        client_max_body_size 10M;

        # Certificates handled by CertBot

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location / {
                server_name sitename www.sitename;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
                # rewrite ^ http://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$server_name/$1 permanent;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
                # root /data/www;
                # index index.html index.htm;
        }
}
```

I want to use rewrite so I redirect https of front-end to http and wp-admin and wp-login as https which is handled by Wordpress.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I do not understand your `location /` block. There should be no `server_name` statement inside the block - I am surprised that `nginx` restarts with this. Check the configuration using `nginx -t`. But the solution that usually works is just `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;`

Comment: @RichardSmith your right, that server_name should not be in `location /` block. I removed it and thanks for the `nginx -t` didn't knew about the test. I can use the `try_files` but then all pages will work in SSL as well which I don't want, I want to redirect all https to http and use the permalink.

Comment: I understand. You need to start with two identical `server` blocks - one for port 80 and one for port 443. You can then fine tune the port 443 configurations to redirect undesirable URIs to `http`.

Comment: @RichardSmith I created separate server block with 443, almost identical and did set `location /` block for it and works great now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a separate similar server block with 443 listen. Included the cert lines and removed the location from 443 block.